# Dictionary/UIColor App Crash

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, crash-reports, uicolor

I recently published an app to the App Store and I have received two crash reports showing some weird behavior with UIColor.

In my app, it has crashed on the last line of code below:

```
let TOK = SubjectObject(subject: .TheoryOfKnowledge, isHL: false)
let EE = SubjectObject(subject: .ExtendedEssay, isHL: false)

// "subjects" is an array of SubjectObjects
subjects.append(TOK)
subjects.append(EE)

// "colorPreferences" is a dictionary
colorPreferences[TOK] = UIColor.init(red: 8/255, green: 32/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
// Crashes here
colorPreferences[EE] = UIColor.init(red: 8/255, green: 32/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Based off of my code, I am fairly certain it has nothing to do with my "EE" object since it is successfully added to the `subjects` array.

One of the frustrating things about this crash is that I can't view the crash message, so I don't know what specifically caused the app to crash. So I don't know why the app would crash on the "EE" dictionary addition but not the "TOK".

I am also wondering if the way I am initializing the UIColor has anything to do with it. I normally intialize UIColors like this:

```
UIColor(red: x, green: y, blue: z, alpha: 1.0)
```

But for some reason, I chose to go with the `init` part. However, I don't see any reason why that would cause the app to crash, perpetuating my confusion.

Both of the crashes have also been in iPhone 6s's but I'm not sure if that's a coincidence or not given that there are only two reports.

If anyone could provide insight into this, that would be much appreciated. If it's possible to find the actual crash message from a iTunes crash report, I would also appreciate learning how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried repeat user action based on backtrace to crash your app?

Comment: @Raymond I've tried to the best of my ability. Ran the failing code the only way the user could on an iPhone 6s. There are other factors I could investigate, but not without knowing what caused the crash

Comment: It doesn't look like this line can crash your app, but maybe I'm wrong. Check other lines executed before crash.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry: On a separate note, 8/255 will result in 0, you might want to change all params to double(CGFloat) by doing this  8.0/255.0

Comment: @PuneetSharma I actually use the same code in multiple other places and the colors are correct so I don't think CGFloats round 8/255 down to zero like Ints would.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry: I think they used to in Objective-C, hence the comment.